# Can't create/get Istio objects via Kubernetes REST API

Tags: istio

We can't get to Istio objects via Kubernetes REST API.

Example:

- `kubectl get gateways`  works and shows all Istio gateways in the default namespace.
- `curl ..../api/v1/namespaces/default/pods` shows all the pods
  deployed in the default name space.
- `curl ..../api/v1/namespaces/default/gateways` returns `404`.

Same is true for `virtualservices`,`serviceentries`, and any other Istio objects.

We have one REST API server running in the cluster.  We are guessing the problem may be caused by it supporting API version `v1` while Istio object creation YAML files refrence API version `networking.istio.io/v1alpha3`.

This is kinda confusing since we can create and get Istio objects via `kubectl` command but cannot do the same by issuing an HTTP request to kubernetes REST API server.  Any insight would be welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I got a couple of ideas when I checked the logs of the kubernetes REST server.  The rest server was discovered as a pod running in the namespace `kube-system`.

Anyhow, every time you need to use kubernetes REST server to get an Istio object created via API version `networking.istio.io/v1alpha3` instead of issuing HTTP request to kubernetes REST server like so `.../api/v1/namespaces/default/gateways` do instead `.../apis/networking.istio.io/v1alpha3/gateways`.  Replace gateways with the name of your Istio object of interest.